# How do I remove the Steam Controller receiver from the USB extender?

Tags: hardware, controllers

I got my Steam Controller and plugged the USB-A receiver into the included desktop extender.

[image: USB receiver plugged into the extender]

But I just tried taking the dongle out of the extender and *I physically can't.* How do I remove it? Has anyone discovered any tricks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pull *very* hard.

It really sticks in there, which is probably good: it's hard to lose.

Comment: And it won't break?

Comment: Mine's still okay, but YMMV.

Comment: I got it out. I'm going to put tape over the slots on the USB port where it locks.

Comment: That was a terrible idea, now I had shreds of tape in the extender.

Comment: @Keavon Unplug and tweezers. I just tried it with a bunch of other USB thingies I have around -- it really is a nice tight fit.

Comment: It's actually easier to remove now. I guess it has to be worn in. The first time, I had to pull so hard that it almost slipped through my fingers.